# fastest Connect 4 win checking method

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to make an ai following the `alpha-beta pruning` method for tic-tac-toe. I need to make checking a win as fast as possible, as the ai will goes through many different possible game states. Right now I have thought of 2 approaches, neither which is very efficient.

1. Create a large tuple for scoring every possible 4 in a row win conditions, and loop through that.
2. Using for loops, check horizontally, vertically, diag facing left, and diag facing right. This seems like it would be much slower that `#1`.

How would someone recommend doing it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you implement it in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it's a bit unclear how your approaches would be implemented. But from the alpha-beta pruning, it seems as if you want to look at a lot of different game states, and in the recursion determine a "score" for each one.

One very important observation is that recursion ends once a 4-in-a-row has been found. That means that at the start of a recursion step, the game board does not have any 4-in-a-row instances.

Using this, we can intuitively see that the new piece placed in said recursion step must be a part of any 4-in-a-row instance created during the recursion step. This greatly reduces the search space for solutions from a total of 69 (21 vertical, 24 horizontal, 12+12 diagonals) 4-in-a-row positions to a maximum of 13 (3 vertical, 4 horizontal, 3+3 diagonal).

This should be the baseline for your second approach. It will require a maximum of 52 (13*4) checks for a naive implementation, or 25 (6+7+6+6) checks for a faster algorithm.

Now it's pretty hard to beat 25 boolean checks for this win-check I'd say, but I'm guessing that your #1 approach trades some extra memory-usage to enable less calculation per recursion step. The simplest way of doing this would be to store 8 integers (single byte is fine for this application) which represent the longest chains of same-color chips that can be found in any of the 8 directions.

Using this, a check for win can be reduced to 8 boolean checks and 4 additions. Simply get the chain lengths on opposite sides of the newly placed chip, check if they're the same color as the chip, and if they are, add their lengths and add 1 (for the newly placed chip).

From this calculation, it seems as if your #1 approach might be the most efficient. However, it has a much larger overhead of maintaining the data structure, and uses more memory, something that should be avoided unless you can pass by reference. Also (assuming that boolean checks and additions are similar in speed) the much harder approach only wins by a factor 2 even when ignoring the overhead.

I've made some simplifications, and some explanations maybe weren't crystal clear, but ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: Just to clarify: I assumed this was about the drop-down version of connect-4, which has 6 rows and 7 columns. However, For "infinite" game boards, the numbers shouldn't change, since it is only a local search. Though it would mean 28 (7+7+7+7) checks instead of 25.